# reference request: construction of uniform tiling

Tags: reference-request, tiling

Wikipedia says "All uniform tilings can be constructed from various operations applied to regular tilings. These operations as named by Norman Johnson are called truncation (cutting vertices), rectification (cutting vertices until edges disappear), and cantellation (cutting edges)."

Can someone please provide some reference for the proof of this statement.